# Comparing columns with different length

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, excel

I try to find for which values difference is more than 1 minute but it always compare along the lines.

How can I firstly find the same values and then compare their times?

```
import pandas as pd
import warnings

warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
df = pd.read_excel('E:/Sesja/Nowy folder/Summary.xlsx')

selected_columns = ['SESSION_NAME', 'TIME', 'SESSION_NAME.1', 'TIME.1']
df_subset = df[selected_columns]

df_subset['DIFFERENCE'] = (pd.to_datetime(df_subset['TIME'].astype(str)) - pd.to_datetime(df_subset['TIME.1'].astype(str))).dt.total_seconds() / 60

result = df_subset[abs(df_subset['DIFFERENCE']) > 1]

print(result)
```

Result - for example index 6

```
  SESSION_NAME      TIME SESSION_NAME.1    TIME.1  DIFFERENCE
0      AA_KRED  00:41:00        AA_KRED  00:12:00        29.0
1      BB_KRED  01:20:00        BB_KRED  00:17:00        63.0
2      CC_RACH  00:17:00        CC_RACH  00:11:00         6.0
3      BB_RACH  00:11:00        BB_RACH  00:01:00        10.0
4     AA_KRED2  00:01:00       AA_KRED2  00:09:00        -8.0
5     BB_KRED2  00:14:00       BB_KRED2  00:08:00         6.0
6     CC_RACH2  00:12:00       BB_RACH2  00:14:00        -2.0
```

[image]

Comment: You want to calc the time difference between TIM and CZAS values of the same SESSION_NAME?

Comment: @gtomer sorry, that was old screen. I want to compare time for the same value in differenct SESSION_NAME columns (after reading it in panda they are called SESSION_NAME and SESSION_NAME.1)

Answer (score 1):

You can merge between the two parts of your dataframe, e.g.:

```
df1 = df[['SESSION_NAME', 'TIME']]
df2 = df[['SESSION_NAME.1', 'TIME.1']]

new_df = pd.merge(left=df1, right=df2, left_on='SESSION_NAME', right_on='SESSION_NAME.1', how='left)
new_df
```

Then you can create `DIFFERENCE` column

Comment: Agreed, although a self-join would be better in the sense that you don't have to create two unnecessary DataFrames just to perform the merge. Additionally, inner join might be better to prevent errors when performing the subtraction as `NaN` values can occur when left-joining, which will cause errors on the subtraction step unless filtered out.

Answer (score 0):

Simply perform a self-join:

```py
new_df = pd.merge(df_subset, df_subset, left_on='SESSION_NAME', right_on='SESSION_NAME.1')
```

You can then calculate the desired difference

Comment: This will result in many duplicate column names - which needs a lot of renaming